# Knative kafka version and python support

Tags: python, apache-kafka, serverless-framework, knative

I want to use Knative for kafka event trigger.
I found a good doc around it https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/kafka/source/index.html.

My questions are:

1. Does it support kafka version 2.5 or higher?
2. I want to write code in python and the file that i came across is in go.
   https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/blob/master/cmd/event_display/main.go

All i want to know can i have the same in python? or would i need a docker image that will use python as base image also in that case what would be the function syntax?

```
def consumer(context, event):
    context.logger.debug(event.body)
    print(event.trigger.kind)
```

I want something like this in Knative event trigger (python)

Answer (score 0):

1. It supports Kafka 2.5, 2.6 not (yet)
2. You can write code in python and you need to build a container image by yourself.

The service or URL referenced by `spec.sink` can be written in any language and in your target language you need to start an HTTP server and listen for events.

In your case, I suggest looking at the Python CloudEvents SDK documentation for receiving events that contains a useful example using Flask: https://github.com/cloudevents/sdk-python/tree/v1.0.0-stable#request-to-cloudevent.

So, the **Knative service** in the Kafka Source example needs to reference your custom container image:

```yaml
# ...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
          image: <your_custom_container_image>
```

Also, `spec.sink` can be a Kubernetes service.
The following is an example configuration to deliver events to a custom path `my-custom-path` for a **Kubernetes service** `my-service`:

```yaml
spec:
  # ...
  sink:
    ref:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Service
      name: my-service
    uri: /my-custom-path
```